# Track multiple top-level domains google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I have a website flexmail.eu
I've added this website to google analytics with multiple domain support

My domains are flexmail.be, flexmail.pl, flexmail.net, ...

How can I configure analytics so I can see how many people came from .be, .nl, .pl, ...

Comment: Have you checked the developer docs? We expect that you do your research https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: I know how to track it, just not how to show it in google analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a customization

Metric Groups: Visits

Dimension Drilldowns: Hostname