# How can I see my multiple domains on Google Analytics page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I inserted the code below on 2 separate domains of mine: www.productsstage.com and www.truthstage.com (which are actually same website underneath).
How can I see how many hits received productsstage.com and how many truthstage.com on https://www.google.com/analytics ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try{
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-61764359-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', window.location.hostname.substring(4)]);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    }catch(e) {}
</script>
```

I did look at this on stackoverflow: [Track multiple top-level domains google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659917/track-multiple-top-level-domains-google-analytics), however it looks like instructions to a previous Google Analytics UI.

Appreciate any help in this.

Jim.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have the same tracking code for two different (albeit similar) sites? Why not track with two different properties?

Comment: You can set "hostname" as a second dimension. For a more permanent solution you can create two views, each with a include filter per hostname (include where hostname contains productstage and where hostname contains thruthstage). As this requires no code it's actually off topic here....

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but I am interested in how to actually see it on Google Analytics webpage. Where to see it? Under which options?. I think I got the Javascript correct (from reading and copying from official documentation)

Nyuen: I need to track it separately in order to see which domain my customers prefer the most.

Comment: @JimD, I have just told you how to do that. "Secondary dimension" is an option in your data tables in the GA interface.

Comment: Listen to @EikePierstorff, he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: @EikePierstorff : Thank you for your response! I did not get what is "second dimension" or "two views". Can you please let me know where I can find documentation on those?

Comment: A "view" in GA is the collection of reports you use daily . You create new views in the rightmost "column" of your admin panel. You can set permanent filters per view (see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en) to include only a part of the collected data that is relevant for this view (e.g. data for a certain hostname). Usually datatables show only one dimension (first column) and associated metrics, however you can set a second dimension from the dropdown in the table header. More info: http://online-metrics.com/secondary-dimensions/.

Comment: Btw. please ask follow-up questions on webmasters.stackexchange.com (as by the house rules SO is limited to programming questions and  this is more about configuration than code).